# Ubuntu 16 R The following signatures couldn't be verified

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-16.04

While updating the package, I am getting below error.

```
sudo apt update


Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried below solutions but none of it works.

**sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9**

**gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9**

**gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -**

Comment: You sure you inserting the righ key?  you should:      sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9

Comment: worked perfect :tup